# Mobile application with intel xdk about rmote database

Tags: php, intel

I am developing a mobile application which has social feature and database driven application. I am done registration and login system with PHP, mysql. But I want to put posting system and want to show the user information on profile section as well as wanting to create update username or password? All those staff are not possible in PHP (am I wrong). So, what is the alternative way to do that (I hear about Jason but do not have proper employee how I can show data). Can someone explain to me please how I can show user data and show my post like Facebook posting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Intel XDK javascript APIs to login and post to Facebook. Below is some sample code and a link to an in-depth tutorial can be found here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/articles/integrating-facebook-functionality-into-hybrid-apps-using-the-intel-xdk

//To login to Facebook

```
alert("about to log into facebook");
document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.facebook.login",function(e){
    if (e.success == true) 
    { console.log("Facebook Log in Successful"); } 
    else 
    { console.log("Unsuccessful Login"); }
},false); 
intel.xdk.facebook.login("publish_stream,publish_actions,offline_access");
```

//To logout of Facebook

```
alert("logging out of facebook");
document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.facebook.logout",function(e){
    if (e.success == true) 
    { console.log("Logged out of Facebook"); } 
    else 
    { console.log("Unsuccessful Logout"); }
},false); 
intel.xdk.facebook.logout();
```

//To GET data from Facebook using Graph API

```
var facebookUserID = "me";  //me = the user currently logged into Facebook
document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.facebook.request.response",function(e) {
    console.log("Facebook User Friends Data Returned");
    if (e.success == true) {
            var data = e.data.data;
            var outHTML = "";

            for (var r=0; r< data.length; r++) {
            outHTML += "<img src='http://graph.facebook.com/" 
                      + data[r]["id"] 
                      + "/picture' info='" 
                      + data[r]["name"] + "' />";
            }
            document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML = outHTML;
            document.removeEventListener("intel.xdk.facebook.request.response");
    } 
},false);
intel.xdk.facebook.requestWithGraphAPI(facebookUserID    
+ "/friends","GET","");
```

//To post user status to feed from Facebook using Graph API

```
var facebookUserID = "me";  //me = the user currently logged into Facebook
document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.facebook.request.response",function(e) {

    if (e.success == true) {
            console.log("Facebook Message posted");
            document.removeEventListener("intel.xdk.facebook.request.response");
    } 
},false);
intel.xdk.facebook.requestWithGraphAPI(facebookUserID + "/{user-id}/feed","POST",
                                      "message={" + message +
                                      "}&access_token={" + access-token + "}");
```